# Stripe: You passed an empty string for 'card'. (works in development)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-deployment, stripe-payments

So I have a rails app set up that is saving a "customer's" credit card information through stripe when they sign up, so that the card can be used for future purchases.  The code runs with no flaws in development on my local machine, but won't run in production on my VPS.  The error I'm getting is this --

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML


Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iwnBhyGlReHmXhlq5QDTgrw9fdXpZnXsX+IoDEp9ufk=", "user"=>{"email"=>"jim@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "meatless"=>"0", "comments"=>"ass", "stripe_card_token"=>""}, "commit"=>"SIGN UP"}
Stripe error while creating customer: You passed an empty string for 'card'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however 'card' cannot be unset. You should remove 'card' from your request or supply a non-empty value
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/login (20.4ms)
```

as you can see, it says `"stripe_card_token"=>""`however, when I do this is development on my local machine, I get success --

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-06 14:39:40 -0500
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"a/NyynWF3loWMYB3KVR0q24mLZHj/KnKJ4/dpOJFTmY=", "user"=>{"email"=>"abs@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "meatless"=>"0", "comments"=>"abs", "stripe_card_token"=>"tok_103GFj2iAIGqhTah4jL5Q3pV"}}
  User Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'abs@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'abs@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("comments", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "customer_id", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_4_digits", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "meatless", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "roles_mask", "sign_in_count", "stripe_customer_token", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18) RETURNING "id"  [["comments", "abs"], ["created_at", Mon, 06 Jan 2014 19:39:42 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["customer_id", nil], ["email", "abs@gmail.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$.NeUFnXgX95FmWJeW4f6ceagVvPgQA.pOINfbqqx1llgxrgTNETim"], ["last_4_digits", "4242"], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["meatless", false], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["roles_mask", nil], ["sign_in_count", 0], ["stripe_customer_token", "cus_3GFj0ZnzTa5Y89"], ["updated_at", Mon, 06 Jan 2014 19:39:42 UTC +00:00]]
   (1.8ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2014-01-06 19:39:42.683904', "current_sign_in_at" = '2014-01-06 19:39:42.683904', "last_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1', "current_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1', "sign_in_count" = 1, "updated_at" = '2014-01-06 19:39:42.684537' WHERE "users"."id" = 9
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

The code is identical... has anyone else had this issue?? What could the problem be?

Comment: did you look at the DB to see if there's card tokens in the user records? if the code's identical, then start looking at where the external things (like db contents) differ.

Comment: While it may not be relevant, a bit of info on the controller, environment(s) stripe config, etc would help build up a fuller picture.

Comment: Are you using javascript to generate your stripe token?  Are you sure that code is working ok on your production server?

Comment: Found the issue, during cap deploy, the file was somehow not coming through, it would say the file existed in my source, but when I clicked to view it, it gave a 404 error.  I eventually just had to move the JS into the actual view in <script> tags to get it to work. Hacky, I know, but it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was running an external JS script called paymentProcess.js, which looked like this --

```
var user;

jQuery(function() {
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'));
  return user.setupForm();
});

user = {
  setupForm: function() {
    return $('.card_form').submit(function() {
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
      if ($('#card_number').length) {
        user.processCard();
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  },
  processCard: function() {
    var card;
    card = {
      number: $('#card_number').val(),
      cvc: $('#card_code').val(),
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val(),
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    };
    return Stripe.createToken(card, user.handleStripeResponse);
  },
  handleStripeResponse: function(status, response) {
    if (status === 200) {
      $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id);
      return $('.card_form')[0].submit();
    } else {
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message);
      return $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
    }
  }
};
```

I am still unsure as to why Capistrano was basically ignoring this file during deployment, but when I moved this JS code into the head of my login.html.erb layout file (in between two `<script>` tags), everything worked great.  Not necessarily a solid answer, but a solid work around for anyone else experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone else, I changed "v2" to "v1" in the embedded Stripe JavaScript and this problem went away.